# how to add UIPickerView into UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipickerview

In Swift 3,i have added UIView to my ViewController and I want to add UIPickerView on the UIView.

When I do:

```
self.picker.delegate = self
self.picker.dataSource = self
```

the app crashes with the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

please help.
thanks..!

Comment: what crash do you experience? Could you post the crash log?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.. and it sign about : self.picker.delegate = self - because he want to show him on the VIEWCONTROLLER and not about the UIVIEW

Comment: it seems your picker is not initialised. Could you post some more code, especially how you set up the pickerView?

Comment: I added the : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource signs.....

Comment: are you using interface builder and `IBOutlet`-s?

Comment: ohh cool thanks.. its just deleted